# Python: combinatory problem with arrays and integers

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, logic, permutation

I've been struggling to try to complete a code because I cannot find a "smart" way to write all the possible combinations of numbers up to a certain string of the value.

With an array and a number as an input, I'd like to find a list of all the possible arrays with numbers for each cell which don't surpass the ones in the same position of the input array and with the sum of all cells not above the total of the input array.

For example, if my inputs are the array `[0 2 4]` and the number 5, I want to find as a result:

```
[[0,0,0], #cannot surpass 0 in position 0
[0,1,0],[0,2,0], #cannot surpass 2 in position 1
[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4], #cannot surpass 4 in position 2
[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,1,4], #cannot surpass total sum 5
[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[0,2,3]) #cannot surpass total sum 5
```

I can write a loop which leads me to the "single digit arrays" (first two rows) but cannot find a way, even recursively, with which to generate de "multiple digits arrays".

I'll show it below

```
cases = []
cases.append([0,0,0])

#single slot additions
for i in range(len(inputArray)):
    if inputArray[i] != 0:
        for j in range(1,inputScalar):
            if j < inputArray[i]:
                zeros=[0,0,0]
                zeros[i]+=j
                cases.append(zeros)
            
print(cases)
```

I don't mind if the solution involves some library or ready-made functions, but I couldn't find one just describing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution from scratch that is more efficient if the sum of the limits  is larger than the max sum.

```
def find_filtered_combs (value_limit, max_sum, i=0, partial=None):
    if partial is None:
        partial = []

    if max_sum < 0:
        pass # No combs to find
    elif max_sum == 0:
        zeros = len(value_limit) - len(partial)
        yield partial + ([0]*zeros)
    elif len(value_limit) <= i:
        yield partial
    else:
        for j in range(value_limit[i]+1):
            partial.append(j)
            yield from find_filtered_combs(value_limit, max_sum - j, i+1, partial)
            partial.pop()


for comb in find_filtered_combs([0, 2, 4], 5):
    print(comb)
```

To see the performance difference, try `find_filtered_combs([2]*30, 2)`.

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. I totally wouldn't have been able of writing this in such a self-invoking way.

Also first time I've seen yield and generators. Had to look up for them.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As someone might find it usefull, I'll post the answer I found out in the end.

I found online what I needed was already written in the library itertools, with which I wrote this:

```
import itertools as itera

cases = []
    
# Create a list of ranges for each cell based on the corresponding value in the input array
# This is better than another layer of for loop I showed in the question

ranges = [range(x+1) for x in inputArray] 
    
# Generate all possible arrays by iterating over all possible values for each cell

for values in itera.product(*ranges):

# Check if the sum of the array is less than or equal to the target sum
    if sum(values) <= targetScalar:
    
# Add the array to the result list if it meets the conditions
        cases.append(list(values))
```

Comment: Note, this works but is inefficient if the sum of the limits is much larger than the target.